# How to merge complementary data within the same DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, merge

I have a complex case of merging partially missing data. I have a DataFrame with all the datapoints:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Name', 'Time', 'C1', 'C2', 'Target1', 'Target2'], 
              data = [['Sample1', 0, 0, 0, np.nan, 1.5],
                      ['Sample1', 24, 0, 0, np.nan, 1.6],
                      ['Sample1', 48, 0, 0, np.nan, 1.7],
                      ['Sample1', 0, 1, 0, np.nan, 2.5],
                      ['Sample1', 24, 1, 0, np.nan, 2.6],
                      ['Sample1', 48, 1, 0, np.nan, 2.7],
                      ['Sample1', 0, 0, 0, 10, np.nan],
                      ['Sample1', 24, 0, 0, 20, np.nan],
                      ['Sample1', 48, 0, 0, 30, np.nan],
                      ['Sample1', 0, 0, 0, np.nan, 1.8]
                      ])

      Name  Time  C1  C2  Target1  Target2
0  Sample1     0   0   0      NaN      1.5
1  Sample1    24   0   0      NaN      1.6
2  Sample1    48   0   0      NaN      1.7
3  Sample1     0   1   0      NaN      2.5
4  Sample1    24   1   0      NaN      2.6
5  Sample1    48   1   0      NaN      2.7
6  Sample1     0   0   0     10.0      NaN
7  Sample1    24   0   0     20.0      NaN
8  Sample1    48   0   0     30.0      NaN
9  Sample1     0   0   0      NaN      1.8
```

Here the lines 0, 1, and 2 have the same characteristics than lines 6, 7, and 8 respectively, so I need them to be merged. Line 9 is the same as line 0 but the same target column so in this case I want to create another column. In the end I want to produce:

```
      Name  Time  C1  C2  Target1  Target2  Target2_x
0  Sample1     0   0   0     10.0      1.5      1.8
1  Sample1    24   0   0     20.0      1.6      NaN
2  Sample1    48   0   0     30.0      1.7      NaN
3  Sample1     0   1   0      NaN      2.5      NaN
4  Sample1    24   1   0      NaN      2.6      NaN
5  Sample1    48   1   0      NaN      2.7      NaN
```

It should work if there are two or more replicates for the same sample. I cannot work out the combination of merge, join, groupby etc. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create counter column by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), remove only `NaN`s columns by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and for correct new columns names with order is used trick with convert columns to `Series`, used another `cumcount` and new columns names was set in list comprehension with `f-string`s:

```
c = ['Name', 'Time', 'C1', 'C2']
df = df.set_index([*c, df.groupby(c).cumcount()]).unstack().dropna(how='all', axis=1)

s = df.columns.to_series().groupby(level=0, sort=False).cumcount()
df.columns = [f'{k}_{v}' for (k, k1), v in s.items()]

df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
      Name  Time  C1  C2  Target1_0  Target2_0  Target2_1
0  Sample1     0   0   0       10.0        1.5        1.8
1  Sample1     0   1   0        NaN        2.5        NaN
2  Sample1    24   0   0       20.0        1.6        NaN
3  Sample1    24   1   0        NaN        2.6        NaN
4  Sample1    48   0   0       30.0        1.7        NaN
5  Sample1    48   1   0        NaN        2.7        NaN
```